# Install PHP on RHEL(4) without root privs

Tags: php, redhat

I am trying to run an Apache/Oracle/PHP server from RedHat(4), from a non-root user.
I've managed to install apache libxml library required for PHP: 
**./configure --prefix=/some/directory/which/i/own/app/php --with-libxml-dir=/some    /directory/which/i/own/app/app/libxml --with-apxs2=/some/directory/which/i/own/app/app/apache/bin/apxs --with-oci8 --with-pdo-oci --with-xmlrpc --enable-soap --disable-phar

./make

./make install**

All looks good, but I don't get any extensions directory.

**../php/bin/php -info | grep extension**

extension_dir => /some/directory/which/i/own/app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626 =>/some/directory/which/i/own/app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626

The extension directory mentioned above does not exists.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can likely just create the directory, or there's an option in the php.ini file, [`extension_dir`](http://php.net/manual/kr/ini.core.php) (it's about halfway down the page, php.net doesn't provide a direct link) -- the same directive you see there when you grep your `php -info` output,  which you can set to whatever directory you'd prefer.

Comment: How would I populate the directory? with what?

Comment: For example, if you download an extension from PECL ( http://pecl.php.net/ ), your installation process will be something like (using the `memcached` extension as an example:  `wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcached-1.0.2.tgz && tar xzf memcached-1.0.2.tgz && cd memcached-1.0.2 && /path/to/your/php/bin/phpize && ./configure && make`, then `make install` .  The `phpize` is the important bit, it does some configuration magic to determine where your extensions should go and what PHP API version it should target, etc.